# Is it safe to read and write on an array of 32 bit data byte by byte?

Tags: c, memory, memory-alignment

So I have a `void *` data of 32 bit unsigned integers which represents the pixels. Is it okay for me to access one of the pixels with a `char *` and modify the values directly? Or is it better to store my new pixel in a temporary `uint32_t` variable and then assign with the correct pointer dereferencing or at least `memcpy`?

Will I have problems with memory alignment or possibly performance depending on the hardware platform?

Comment: array is continuous set of bytes, so there should be no problems. Until it is one-dimensional, and there are no structs, which can be aligned by compiler.

Comment: You've said that one pixel occupies 32 bit. You obviously need to know the sub-structure of a 32 bit pixel value (i.e. which bits represent which channels, such as R, G, B, A). Endianness *may* come into play here, but memory alignment shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It's safe as long as you are not talking about multitasking app that can change a global variable, or interrupt (a timer) that use that variable.

Comment: @LPs: Those issues are true for any global variable in general, and are not particularly special with regards to the specific question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  The only danger would be generating a bit pattern that does not correspond to any int, but on modern systems there are no such patterns.  Also, if the data type was `uint32_t` specifically, those are prohibited from having any such patterns anyway.

Note that the inverse situation of using a `uint32_t` to write multiple `char`s at once is not permitted (strict aliasing rule).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine.

Arrays don't have unused bytes inside them, so if you use `uint32_t` you can be sure that each element uses exactly 32 bits.